# Can HTTP deliver video over the internet or is that TCP?

Tags: networking, http, bittorrent, tcp, network-protocols

The post below talks about delivering video content to users via HTTP. Is it confusing it with the TCP protocol?

https://torrentfreak.com/torrents-time-brings-popcorn-time-to-any-windows-browser-160202/

Comment: Could you put the possibly-wrong material (or a summary thereof) in the question itself?

Comment: Ben, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please clarify and explain why this needs to be done?

Comment: @Saae can you quote the parts of the article you need help clarifying in your question? This is in case the external link ever goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is based on/using TCP, as many other protocols do, like FTP, SSH, SMTP, IMAP and so on. They are using features of TCP (like stateful connections, resend when a packet is lost etc), but how data is structured and transfered is up to the higher level protocols, like HTTP.

Actually, you can transfer data using only TCP, but this is more of "Possible but nobody does it" thing, as TCP itself has no comfort or features for doing so.

So - the article is correct. The video files are delivered via HTTP or Bittorrent Protocol, which are both using TCP for the transfer, but doing it "their own way".